# How to create a bunch of key pairs when benchmarking?

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark

I want to benchmark verifying sr25519 signatures and for that I need to create a bunch of key pairs, sign some data, then benchmark the verification process, however using `sp_core::sr25519::Pair` is not allowed, it throws this error:

```rs
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sp_core::sr25519::Pair`
 --> /home/test/projects/custom/pallet/src/benchmarking.rs:8:5
  |
8 | use sp_core::sr25519::Pair;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Pair` in `sr25519`
```

I assume this is happening because it could be leaking some std features in Pair so it wouldn't compile, so how do I solve this?

PS: I'm not tied necessarily to that specific struct (in fact this is the first time going to work with it); I used to work with a `cryptostore` that generates `sr25519` keys, so anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```rust
use sp_io::crypto::{sr25519_generate, sr25519_sign};
```

```rust
let caller_public = sr25519_generate(key_type_id, None);
```

And if you need a Substrate account from your sr25519 public key:

```rust
let caller = MultiSigner::Sr25519(caller_public).into_account().into();
```

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/943c520aa78fcfaf3509790009ad062e8d4c6990/frame/nfts/src/benchmarking.rs#L804-L805).

Comment: this worked thanks

Comment: hi can i know how to use bounded_vec macro in benchmarks 
i have posted my question over here
(https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10118/how-to-use-bounded-vec-macro-in-benchmarking-rs)